# Move a UIView with my finger

Tags: ios, uiview, move, touchesbegan

I'm trying to move a UIView (let's call it viewA), which is located on top of another UIView (let's call it viewB). viewB has the size of the iPad screen, and view A is much much smaller.

I manage to move things, but the whole screen moves (viewA + viewB), not only viewA.

Here is my code for viewA class:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self->view];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.window.frame, touchLocation)) {
            dragging = YES;
            oldY = touchLocation.y;
        }
    }
```

`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self->view];
    if (dragging) {
        CGRect frame = self.window.frame;
        frame.origin.y =  self.window.frame.origin.y + touchLocation.y - oldY;
        self.window.frame = frame;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    dragging = NO;
}`

What I do not understand, is that, I implemented these methods in the viewA class. "Self" should concern this viewA, right? So why does the whole page move when my finger move on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving the entire window, which contains all the views, you should only move the view you want, viewA in your case.